# I copied the bluetooth code in my android project but it is showing error that cannot be resolved to a field

Tags: android, types, bluetooth, field

I copied the bluetooth code in my android project but it is showing error that cannot be resolved to a field:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent serverIntent = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.connect_scan:
        // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
        serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
        return true;
    case R.id.discoverable:
        // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
        ensureDiscoverable();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it shows that R.id.connect_scan cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: What is your question? For the sake of clarity, could you indent your code properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows you that error because

- Either you forgot to copy the option_menu.xml or did not copy properly
- You need to rebuild your project

Comment: i copied it properly.
it is showing error because the entries are not added to R.java file. please help